# Getting an error of: "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79" in Selenium Phython

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am using Chrome Browser version 81.0.4044.113 and my Selenium was working properly days ago. Now when I enter the code below, I get an error message saying that I need to use Chrome version 79.

I have seen people say that you need to downgrade Chrome, but this does not seem to be the problem for me, as I had Selenium working properly days ago.

**My code:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
chromeOptions=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Downloads\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",options=chromeOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the <kbd>webdriver-manager</kbd>, where it will take care of downloading the correct version of the webdriver based on the browser version and OS. Also with the necessary permissions too. (like `os.chomp`). Here is the pip installation for webdriver_manager

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Below is the sample script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chromeOptions=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit
```

Comment: I shouldn't have to use webdriver manager everytime I write a piece of code

Comment: If you have a framework/def then it's a one time job, where you will write the def to get the browser as the param and then you can pass that to the webdriver manager. By that way you just have to call the def, rather replicating the lines  `everytime I write a piece of code` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try execute the code below to identify the compatible versions:

```
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
```

To establish a connection, try

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="73.0.3683.68", extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```